# Lie derivative and Levi-Civita connection example calculation

Tags: differential-geometry

So I'm trying to understand the differences between the Lie derivative and a connection. I'm considering the following example and wondering if it illustrates this. Say we consider the vector fields $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $Y=e^y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in $\Bbb R^2$. On the $x$-axis these two are equal and so one would expect that $\mathcal{L}_X\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \mathcal{L}_Y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, but it turns out that $$\mathcal{L}_X\frac{\partial}{\partial y}= \left[X,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right] = 0$$ and $$\mathcal{L}_Y\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \left[Y,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right] = -e^y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$$

So they aren't equal. If we would have instead considered the Levi-Civita connection these would have been equal due to the Christoffel symbols vanishing right?

Could anyone help me understand what is happening here and why these two have so different results?

Comment: Except for $\mathcal{L}_X\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \mathcal{L}_Y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ the other formulas look right. "If we would have instead considered the Levi-Civita connection these would have been equal due to the Christoffel symbols vanishing right?" I don't get this. When Christoffel symbols vanish then $\partial=\nabla$ so why should there be any difference? I suggest that you write out the question more clearly.

Comment: When the Christoffel symbols vanish we have that $\nabla_X \frac{\partial}{\partial y} = 0 = \nabla_Y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. @KurtG.

Comment: True. And? $\phantom{.}$

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a coment:

For any two vector fields
$$\tag{1}
X=X^\mu\partial_\mu\,,\quad Y=Y^\mu\partial_\mu
$$ we know that the [Lie dervative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#The_Lie_derivative_of_a_vector_field)
is the difference of two directional derivatives
$$\tag{2}
{\cal L}_XY=[X,Y]=\partial_XY-\partial_YX\,.
$$
Whether or not Christoffel symbols vanish we also know that the
covariant derivative is
$$\tag{3}
\nabla_\mu X^\nu=\partial_\mu X^\nu+\Gamma^\nu_{\rho\mu}X^\rho\,.
$$
Therefore, the $\nu$-th component of the directional derivative $\partial_YX$ is
$$\tag{4}
Y^\mu\nabla_\mu X^\nu=Y^\mu\partial_\mu X^\nu+\Gamma^\nu_{\rho\mu}X^\rho Y^\mu\,.
$$
Likewise, the $\nu$-th component of the directional derivative $\partial_XY$ is
$$\tag{5}
X^\mu\nabla_\mu Y^\nu=X^\mu\partial_\mu Y^\nu+\Gamma^\nu_{\rho\mu}Y^\rho X^\mu\,.
$$
Since the Christoffel symbols of the Levi-Civita connection are symmetric in their
lower indices it follows that the Christoffel terms cancel (regardless of $\Gamma$ being zero or not). Therefore,
$$\tag{6}
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}
{\cal L}_XY=[X,Y]=\partial_XY-\partial_YX=\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX\,.\quad}
$$
Now over to you. What exactly are you asking?